# Why can't I wrap a template parameter with parentheses?

Tags: c++, templates, macros, preprocessor

to avoid XY, I will start by explaining my overall goal.

I'm trying to make a choice between two different generic containers at compile-time. The solutions I came up with is very straightforward using macros. For the sake of demonstaration here is how it would look with `std::vector` and `std::set` (in practice they're other containers but it's irrelevant to the issue)

```cpp
// switch between the container types
//#define CONT_SET

#ifdef CONT_SET
#define CONTAINER(type) std::set<type>
#else
#define CONTAINER(type) std::vector<type>
#endif

int main() {
    CONTAINER(float) cont;    
}
```

this works perfectly fine.
The problem arises when I try to store more complicated types in the container, for example

```
CONTAINER(std::pair<int, int>) cont;
```

this will not work, because the compiler detects this as two different macro parameters `std::pair<int` and `int>`.
I tried overcoming this issue by adding parantheses that group the entire type together

```
CONTAINER((std::pair<int, int>)) cont;
```

but then I get a 'template argument 1 is invalid' [(godbolt)](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:2,endLineNumber:17,positionColumn:2,positionLineNumber:17,selectionStartColumn:2,selectionStartLineNumber:17,startColumn:2,startLineNumber:17),source:%27%23include+%3Cvariant%3E%0A%23include+%3Cstring%3E%0A%23include+%3Ciostream%3E%0A%23include+%3Cvector%3E%0A%23include+%3Cset%3E%0A%0A%23define+CONT_SET%0A%0A%23ifdef+CONT_SET%0A%23define+CONTAINER(type)+std::set%3Ctype%3E%0A%23else%0A%23define+CONTAINER(type)+std::vector%3Ctype%3E%0A%23endif%0A%0Aint+main()+%7B%0A++++CONTAINER((std::pair%3Cint,+int%3E))+cont%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:54.98039215686275,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:gsnapshot,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%271%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%270%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-std%3Dc%2B%2B2a%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1,tree:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+gcc+(trunk)+(C%2B%2B,+Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:63.311058686183955,l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:1,editor:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,tree:%271%27,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+gcc+(trunk)+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:45.01960784313725,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)

is there a way to tell the compiler that the entire expression is just one macro parameter? or that the parenthesized template parameter is a valid type?

Comment: What about `using`, `typedef` alias respecively?? Might need a `template` along.

Comment: For the XY part: There is no need to use a macro for this. You can simply use type aliases. Do you still want to ask about the macro issue or rather an alternative without macros?

Comment: You could simply use `#define CONTAINER(...) std::set<__VA_ARGS__>`

Comment: Why not just simply `template<class T> using XXX = std::conditional_t<xxx, std::vector<T>, std::set<T>>`?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ the thing is that macros leak through files. I know usually it's considered a horrible aspect of macros, but in this case it's an advantage. I'm trying to provide a library where the consumer of the header has the choice to set or unset this switch globally to the entire library, and I don't know about any way to get `using`s to work like that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Premised that I think that C/C++ macros are distilled evil (and that seems to me that you can substitute `Container()` using `using`) you can pass throug a type alias

```
using pair_i_i = std::pair<int, int>;

CONTAINER(pair_i_i) cont;
```

Answer (score 3):

To the preprocessor, `std::pair<int, int>` looks like two template arguments, `std::pair < int` and `int >` because the comma isn't guarded. But also extra parentheses generally aren't allowed in type names, so `(std::pair<int, int>)` is not syntatically valid.

There are a few way to remedy this:

- If your type is the last argument of your function macro (like it is in your case), you can make it variadic:

```cpp
#define CONTAINER(...) std::vector< __VA_ARGS__ >
```

- You can use a comma macro that you don't need to guard:

```cpp
#define COMMA ,

CONTAINER(std::pair<int COMMA int>) cont;
```

- You can introduce a type alias that doesn't have commas

```cpp
using cont_value = std::pair<int, int>;

CONTAINER(cont_value) cont;
```

- You can introduce parentheses to guard the comma in a different way (here I use the parentheses in `decltype(...)`)

```cpp
#define GUARD_TYPE_NAME(...) typename decltype(std::type_identity< __VA_ARGS__ >())::type

CONTAINER(GUARD_TYPE_NAME(std::pair<int, int>)) cont;
```

Comment: `GUARD_TYPE_NAME` might as well expand to `__VA_ARGS__`, the parentheses required to call it are enough. :)

Answer (score 3):

I think that a cleaner solution is to encapsulate whatever you're doing inside your own type:

```cpp
template <typename type> 
class my_container
{
#ifdef CONT_SET
    std::set<type> cont;
#else
    std::vector<type> cont;
#endif
};

int main() {
    my_container<int> a;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
// switch between the container types
//#define CONT_SET

#ifdef CONT_SET
template <typename T>
using container = std::set<T>;
#else
template <typename T>
using container = std::vector<T>;
#endif
```

That reduces the use of macros, which is always good.

Comment: I think this is the cleanest answer.

Answer (score 0):

The most common way to get around this problem is by aliasing using `using` as the other answers mentioned.

However, here is another way using template specialization if you want to avoid using parameterized macros and also be able to make some of your `Container` variables independent of `CONT_SET`.

```cpp
#define CONT_SET

#ifdef CONT_SET
#define MYTYPE signed  // selects set.
#else
#define MYTYPE unsigned  // selects vector.
#endif

#define SET signed     // selects set.
#define VECTOR signed  // selects vector.

// General case
template <typename T1, typename T2>
class Container {};

// Specialized when T2=unsigned, selects vector.
template <typename T1>
class Container<T1, unsigned> {
 public:
  std::vector<T1> c;
};

// Specialized. When T2=signed, selects set.
template <typename T1>
class Container<T1, signed> {
 public:
  std::set<T1> c;
};

int main() {
  // This one uses set or vector depending on CONT_SET
  Container<int, MYTYPE> my_cont;

  // This one uses set
  Container<int, SET> set_cont;

  // This one uses vector
  Container<int, VECTOR> vector_cont;
  return 0;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/q9W39s7qx

Answer (score 0):

BOOST_IDENTITY_TYPE is the solution for that:
https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/libs/utility/identity_type/doc/html/index.html

You can also wrap the type into decltype:
`decltype(std::pair<int, int>()) var;`
which also adds an extra parentheses,
but this unfortunately does an extra ctor call.